# How do I implement Typescript webdriverio for the SpectronClient?

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io, ava, spectron

[Spectron](https://github.com/electron/spectron) is a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) framework for automating [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) apps.  I'm using Spectron along with [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava) and [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to do automated Integration Testing.  I'm using [AVA's suggest method](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/typescript.md) for making the test's context typesafe but I'm not able to figure out how to get typesafety on the Spectron's client property which is a [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io) client. I'm only able to see a few properties which the Spectron typescript definition file has provided and this is causing typescript transpile errors.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
src/pages/drive-shell.ts(7,34): error TS2339: Property 'waitForVisible' does not exist on type 'SpectronClient'.
src/pages/login.ts(7,34): error TS2339: Property 'waitForVisible' does not exist on type 'SpectronClient'.
src/pages/login.ts(11,21): error TS2339: Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'SpectronClient'.
src/pages/login.ts(12,21): error TS2339: Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'SpectronClient'.
src/pages/login.ts(13,21): error TS2339: Property 'click' does not exist on type 'SpectronClient'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved this as I was typing up the question but figured since I did some searching and couldn't find any solutions I thought I might answer my own question in order to help others.

I needed to get the typings for webdriver io

```
npm i -S @types/webdriverio
```

and then I imported that type into my `login.ts` script and use that as the SpectronClient

```
import * as WebdriverIO from 'webdriverio';
export class Login {
    constructor(private client: WebdriverIO.Client<void>) { }

    public async waitForPageToLoad() {
        return await this.client.waitForVisible('#username');
    }

    public login(username: string, password: string) {
        this.client.setValue('#username', username);
        this.client.setValue('#Password', password);
        this.client.click('#login');
    }
}
```

and here is my full `test.ts` test script

```
import * as ava from 'ava';
import { Application } from 'spectron';
import { Login } from './pages/login';
import { Settings } from './settings';

function contextualize<T>(getContext: () => Promise<T>): ava.RegisterContextual<T> {
    ava.test.beforeEach(async (t) => {
        Object.assign(t.context, await getContext());
    });
    return ava.test;
}
const test = contextualize(async () => {
    const app = new Application({
        path: '../electron.exe',
        args: ['../app/index.html'],
    });
    await app.start();
    return { app };
});

test.afterEach.always(async (t) => await t.context.app.stop());

test('can login', async (t) => {
    const login = new Login(t.context.app.client);
    await login.waitForPageToLoad();
    login.login(Settings.username, Settings.password);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As of right now (July 2019), WebdriverIO has moved to version 5.0, but Spectron still uses WebdriverIO 4. Make sure to specify the version used in Spectron when installing the WebdriverIO typings to resolve this issue:

```
npm i -S @types/webdriverio@^4.8.0
```

Comment: Yup. That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After spending almost one entire day and digging deep into the source code I found the [Spectron](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#client) documentation is wrong.

It clearly says,

> Spectron uses WebdriverIO and exposes the managed client property on the created Application instances. The client API is WebdriverIO's browser object.

But as can be seen in the [WebdriverIO documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$/) the functions like `click`, `setValue`, etc are not part of the `browser` object. They are available under the [`element` object](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/setValue). So here is what I did,

```
const inputText = await app.client.$('user_name'); // get hold of the element
inputText.click(); // get access to the WebdriverIO functions
```